# How upload images and preview these

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm making my own CMS. It is meant that you can upload the images and then view them as preview. Additionally, for several different images, elements (on a page) must be possible.

Below is an image with what I mean

[image: explanation of the text]

```
<div class="row">
<div class="seven columns">
    <div class="gallery"></div>
</div>
<div class="five columns" style="height:50vh;">
    <input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add"><br />
    <input type="text" name="alt" placeholder="alt">
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
// Multiple images preview in browser
var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

    if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }

};

$('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
}); });
```

I do have code to make this work for 1x. But if I paste this 2x then this does not work

Comment: start with code

Comment: Well if you repeat that HTML block several times, you need to modify the ID, because IDs need to be unique within the scope of an HTML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
function readURL(input, id) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function(event) {
             $('#'+id).attr('src', event.target.result);
         }
         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
}
    
$("#img").change(function(){
   readURL(this, 'preview');
});

$("#img1").change(function(){
   readURL(this, 'preview1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" runat="server">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180" id="preview">
    <input type='file' id="img"/>
    
    <img src="http://placehold.it/180" id="preview1">
    <input type='file' id="img1"/>
</form>
```

Maybe this helps you

Comment: This does not work if I put more than 1 <input type = 'file'> on 1 page

Comment: Try updated code

Comment: I do not mean that with multiple images. I would like multiple <input> buttons so that I can place another image in multiple places. (this is because of positioning of the images.)

Comment: ok try new code

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you